# How can I specify which field in the user table to be bind to name attribute of the CWebUser?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I found that yii can get and echo the user name by this :

```
    echo Yii::app()->user->name;
```

my question is how can I specify the field in the table user to be bind with the CWebUser::name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config

```
// application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication 
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'class'=>'WebUser',
        ),
```

WebUser class (example for "email" field from table "user"):

```
  class WebUser extends CWebUser
    {
        public function getEmail() 
        {    
            if(!$this->getState('__email')&&$this->id)
            {
                $user = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
                $this->setState('__email', $user->email);
            }
            $state = $this->getState('__email');
            return $state;
        }

        public function login($identity, $duration=0) 
        {
            $this->allowAutoLogin = true;
            parent::login($identity, $duration);
            $this->id = $identity->id;
            if (!$this->isGuest)
            {
                if($user = User::model()->findByPk($this->id))
                {
                    $this->setState('__email', $user->email);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own UserIdentity component by extending CUserIdentity, and in authenticate() method after user identification declare $this->username = $user->variable;